# why is "this" pointer scope in javascript restricted?

Tags: javascript, closures

Scope or visibility of the `this` pointer which is called w.r.t a div is restricted to the function to which it was intended to and not to its NESTED functions.

But,all the local variables of that function are visible in the nested functions -- why does this happen??.. getting the `this` pointer via calling the function with `<function name>(this)` on a div -- doesnt this mean even the `this` pointed also is a local variable in the `<function name>`

In short, here's the code which confused me..

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function tst1(){
    setTimeout(
    function (){
    alert(this.id)
    }, 2000)
    }
    function tst2(){
    var elem = this
    setTimeout(
    function (){
    alert(elem.id)
    }, 2000)
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .test{
    margin: 40px 100px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div id="fooBar"  class="test" onclick="tst1.call(this)"> Emily Rossum</div>
<div id="chickenRun" class="test" onclick="tst2.call(this)"> Emily Rossum</div>
</html>
```

In the `tst1 function` the `this` variable is `null` but the local variable of that function should be visible in the nested functions as shown in `tst2`.

I was reading on closures, since the function is being called later -- via `setTimeout` even after the `tst1` and `tst2` are returned -- aren't both the functions closures? (If so,this being a variable in the parent function should be visible in the nested function, shouldn't it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` variable in javascript is different from other variables in that it's always specific to the particular function invocation.  There is essentially one `this` for every function invocation and it's not necessarily, although it may be, the same `this` which was used to in the outer function.

If you want to preserve the outer `this` for use within the inner functions then save it to a local.

```
var outer = function () { 
  var self = this;  // Save current 'this' in a local
  var inner = function () { 
    self.name;  // refers to the original outer 'this.name' 
    ...
  };
  ...
};
```

Comment: that's what i'm doing in `tst2` .. i know u can access it when you copy it,my point was why was the `this` from the parent not accessible in the nested function when the state of the parent is supposed to be saved for the nested to access even after the function is returned.. as in the __references__ from the parent function(i guess including the `this`) should be accessible in the nested..

Comment: @VivekChandra it's because every function has a `this` hence you're always asking the `this` of the current function and not the saved one.  It's the same for any local.  If the outer and inner function have locals of the same name you can never access the outer one, only the inner one.